# Clean up &amp; style characters from text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting text from a feed that has alot of characters like:

```
Insignia&amp;#153; 2.0 Stereo Computer Speaker System (2-Piece) - Black
4th-Generation Apple&#174; iPod&#174; touch
```

Is there an easy way to get rid of these, or do I have to anticipate which characters I want to delete and use the delete method to remove them?  Also, when I try to remove

```
&amp;
```

with

```
str.delete("&amp;")
```

It leaves behind "amp;"  Is there a better way to delete this type of character?  Do I need to re-encode the text?

Comment: I presume you've noticed the spelling difference between `&amp;` and `&amb;`? Hopefully this just a typo in the question? (if so, please edit the question to fix it!)

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of them and not just replace them with the character they represent (`&`)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[String#delete](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_string.html#String.delete) is certainly not what you want, as it works on characters, not the string as a whole.

Try

```
str.gsub /&amp;/, ""
```

You may also want to try replacing the `&amp;` with a literal ampersand, such as:

```
str.gsub /&amp;/, "&"
```

If this is closer to what you really want, you may get the best results unescaping the HTML string. If so try this:

```
CGI::unescapeHTML(str)
```

Details of the unescapeHTML method are [here](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/cgi/1.9.2/CGI#unescapeHTML-class_method).

Comment: Be careful with `unescapeHTML` if you don't trust the source to be clean of malicious html.

Comment: Note that if this is an RSS feed, then the best solution is not to roll your own at all but to use a dedicated RSS feed parser such as [simple-rss](http://rubygems.org/gems/simple-rss) or [similar](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/feed_parsing).

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting data from a 'feed', aka RSS XML, then you should be using an XML parser like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) to process the XML. This will automatically unescape HTML entities and allow you to get the proper string representation directly.

Comment: It exactly according to my requirements (Y)

Answer (score -1):

For removing try to use gsub method, something like this:

```
text = "foo&amp;bar"
text.gsub /\b&amp;\b/, ""  #=> foobar
```

Comment: `"foo&amp;&amp;1".gsub( /\b&amp;\b/, '&' ) #=> "foo&amp;&amp;1"` You should not have the `\b` in that regex.